# Set possible values for a function argument in R (ex: f <- function(x){} where x must be `a` or `b`)

Tags: r, function, arguments

In R, how do I define a function like `f <- function(x){...}` which can only take the argument `x` to be `'a'` or `'b'`?

[BTW, what is the current (as of 2020) best/easy/practical package for creating functions in R? Is it still roxygen?]

Comment: Maybe `if(!x %in% c('a', 'b')) stop('Input should be either a or b')` in the first line of the function.

Comment: Also, roxygen does not create functions. It simply allows you to document your functions if you are creating a package. And typically asking for "best" solutions for something is usually an opinion based question which is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `f <- function(x = c("a","b")) { x <- match.arg(x); ... }`?

Comment: @MrFlick good point, I slipped in the question. I will edit later.

Comment: @r2evans, tks. This sees great. But, does R now not to consider the vector `c("a","b")` as de default value for `x`?

Comment: Yes it does, until you call [`match.arg`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.arg.html). Its default is `several.ok=FALSE`, so with the default behavior, that code in my previous comment will only allow a single value. This means that while the function definition *suggests* a vector is accepted, only the first is used. (Typically this ambiguity is explicitly discussed in the function help docs.) Notice, though, that it does partial matching (ala `pmatch`), so `match.arg('a',c('aa','bb'))` returns `"aa"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One canonical (idiomatic) way in R to allow one of so many values for a function argument is to use `match.arg`:

```r
f <- function(x = c("a", "b")) {
  x <- match.arg(x)
}
```

Since it defaults to `several.ok=FALSE`, it reduces `x` to a single argument. If nothing is provided, then it will default to the first value in the vector.

However, note that since it uses `pmatch` internally, it allows partial matching. This means:

```r
match.arg('a',c('aa','bb'))
# [1] "aa"
```

which may not be desired. In that case, then RonakShah's first suggestion (modified to check length as well) is likely the most direct, one of the following `if` statements:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x) || length(x) != 1L || !x %in% c("a", "b")) {
    stop("'x' argument must be one of: 'a','b'")
  }
  ### or, if 'x' can have length>1, then
  if (is.null(x) || !length(x) || !all(x %in% c("a", "b"))) {
    stop("'x' argument must be one of: 'a','b'")
  }
  # ...
}
```

If `x` can legitimately have a length greater than 1, update the conditional to be `!all(x %in% c("a","b"))`.

FYI: `roxygen` is not for creating functions. I believe its power initially was that it kept the documentation in the same place as the code, which *might* prod the developer into updating the documentation when the function itself is modified. I believe in practice that this is perhaps too optimistic, especially with large functions where the roxygen docs are well off the page.

However, another benefit (in a subsequent release) is that it supports markdown-formatted documentation, no longer requiring the user to use R-centric formatting (e.g., for URLs, links to other R functions/packages, code, emphasis, etc).

Comment: tks. Great. Another advantage of the second approach is customizing the error message